# Is it possible to call a function from and dotnet assemble from a MS SQL query?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server

Is it possible to call a function from and dotnet assemble from a MS SQL query?

Comment: I'm just curious ... why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a [CLR Stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx) as long as you are using SQL Server 2005 or 2008.

You can also create CLR triggers, UDFs and few others.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_CLR